# Speed of Javascript executed inside Qt with QJSEngine

Tags: javascript, c++, performance, qt, qjsengine

**Background:**
I am working in a project that requires the following: the user can write commands to perform some mathematical operations with internal variables of the main program (a GUI written in Qt/C++).

My approach is a text box where the user can write the commands/scripts in JavaScript and then Qt evaluates that code. To that end I am using [QJSEngine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsengine.html)

**The Problem**:
The computation speed of JavaScript is very bad/slow.

For example, we have a just a GUI with two text boxes (QTextEdit) and one button. In one textbox the user writes the JavaScript code and when the button is pressed it is evaluated and the result appears in the other textbox.

As an example of the bad performance, when the user writes this trivial JavaScript code the computer spends ~3 seconds to show the answer:

```
var X = [];
for (var i=0 ; i < 934600 ; ++i )
{
   X[i] = i;
}
X[120]
```

On the other hand, if the same operation is performed in Qt/C++, it is "instantaneous":

```
QVector<double> myVec;
for(int i=0; i < 934600; ++i)
{
  myVec.append(i);
}
qDebug() << myVec.value(120);
```

I know that JavaScript is a interpreted language, but is it normal this performance?

Here you have a small Qt sample program (pr_Parser) to show this problem. I have tested this in Qt Creator 4.0.1. With Qt 5.7 MSVC2013 64 bits.

Thank you.

### pr_parser.pro

```
QT       += core gui qml    
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets    
TARGET = pr_Parser
TEMPLATE = app    
CONFIG += c++11    
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        CMainWindow.cpp    
HEADERS  += CMainWindow.h
```

### main.cpp

```
#include "CMainWindow.h"
#include <QApplication>    
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   CMainWindow w;
   w.show();
   return a.exec();
}
```

### CMainWindow.h

```
#include <QMainWindow>
class QPlainTextEdit;    
class CMainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
   CMainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
   ~CMainWindow();    
private:
   QPlainTextEdit *m_p_myScriptWindow;
   QPlainTextEdit *m_p_myResultWindow;    
private slots:
   void slot_ExecuteScript();
};
```

### CMainWindow.cpp

```
#include "CMainWindow.h"
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QJSEngine>

    CMainWindow::CMainWindow(QWidget *parent)
   : QMainWindow(parent)
{
   QWidget *window = new QWidget(this);
   setCentralWidget(window);
   QString sampleScript = "var X = [];";
   sampleScript.append("for (var i=0 ; i < 934600 ; ++i ){X[i]=i;}");
   sampleScript.append("X[120]");
   m_p_myScriptWindow = new QPlainTextEdit(sampleScript, this);
   m_p_myResultWindow = new QPlainTextEdit(this);
   QPushButton *myButton = new QPushButton("Execute", this);
   QVBoxLayout *myLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
   myLayout->addWidget(m_p_myScriptWindow);
   myLayout->addWidget(myButton);
   myLayout->addWidget(m_p_myResultWindow);
   window->setLayout(myLayout);
   connect(myButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slot_ExecuteScript()));
}

CMainWindow::~CMainWindow(){}

void CMainWindow::slot_ExecuteScript()
{
   QJSEngine myEngine;
   QString myScript = m_p_myScriptWindow->toPlainText();
   QJSValue myValue = myEngine.evaluate(myScript);
   if(myValue.isError())
   {
    m_p_myResultWindow->setPlainText(myValue.property("message").toString());
   }
   else
   {
      m_p_myResultWindow->setPlainText(myValue.toString());
   }

   // This code is "instanteneous"
   // QVector<double> myVec;
   // for(int i=0; i < 934600; ++i) {myVec.append(i);}
   // m_p_myResultWindow->setPlainText(QString::number(myVec.value(120)));
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that Qt's `QJSEngine` is designed for use in QML, and is not intended as a highly-performant general-purpose JS engine. If the performance you currently get is OK, that's fine. But you will have a much better performing system if you use another engine, like v8, if your functions do significant amount of work. If the functions are very short, `QJSEngine` should be faster since it has very little overhead.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know how to use another engine. I have seen [this](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Script_V8_Port) but it states that is abandoned. The "commands" that I intend to use in JavaScript are just array operations (sums, multiplications, etc), with arrays of around 1e6 values

Comment: If you want the best performance for looping through 1e6 elements, you'll probably want v8. Of course it's up to you to build it and integrate it, it won't have a Qt front-end, but it's not really necessary. See [google v8 embedding documentation](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Getting%20Started%20with%20Embedding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer.

The problem was that I was compiling it in Debug mode.
In release mode is 10 times faster.

Measured times (with QElapsedTimer) executing it several times:

JavaScript script:

- In Debug mode   : 2900 - 3000 ms
- In Release mode :  255 -  300 ms

The same "for" in native Qt/C++:

- In Debug mode   : 26 - 29 ms
- In Release mode :  7 -  6 ms